# Как сделать эффект появляющегося движущего блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

Вот пример с Яндекс еды, блок доставки похож на блок шторки уведомлений в вашем смартфоне.

При вызове блока он выезжает снизу, его можно взять сверху и потянуть, блок будет задвигаться обратно, но если потянуть не сильно он вернется в исходное положение, а если вы увели блок больше половины он скрывается.

К тому же в зависимости от того насколько сильно вы будете тянуть блок вниз будет уменьшаться затемнение на заднем плане.

Можно ли сделать такой же или похожий эффект используя только CSS + Нативный Javascript
В крайнем случае Jquery[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде можно, проблем не вижу, делайте :)

Comment: Так подскажите пожалуйста, какие стили для этого нужны? У меня получается сделать чтобы он выезжал и заезжал обратно с помощью анимаций. Но мне нужно чтобы это было интерактивно

Comment: `width`, `height`, `display`, `margin`, `padding`, `background`, `fill`, `color`, `border-radius`, `position: absolute`, `top`, `bottom`, `transform: translate`, `@keyframes` и ещё может быть `opacity`, но я не уверен. Ищите всё в поисковике для более подробной информации о них. Если вы уже ознакомлены с этими пропорциями, тогда начинайте делать, возникнут проблемы, приходите.

Comment: Появился вопрос, я смог сделать Анимацию с помощью использования transform: translate. Однако в какие то моменты мне необходимо чтобы блок прокрутился самостоятельно, например при его вызове. В этом случае я использовал setInterval и менял его translateY однако это было либо слишком медленно либо слишком рвано. С использованием requestAnimationFrame такая же ситуация, я сравниваю анимацию у Яндекс еды и там получается намного плавнее, как мне можно добиться плавной и быстро анимации? Например при выезде блока из низа экрана

Comment: странно... Обычно с `requestAnimationFrame` не должно быть проблем, можете [задавать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), где вам смогут помочь и другие участники? Заодно  опубликуете ваши попытки в вопросе, а там уже и разберёмся что не так. (И добавьте больше подробностей, то что у вас написано в комментарии - мало)